# aureport -l doesnt show the sucessful count of the user who used "su" command

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, audit, linux-audit

why the command `aureport -l --success --summary -i` does show the successful login count of the user who used `su` command.

The output the above said command only calculates `sshd`, `gdm` sessions but not `su`. What should I do if I want to know the exact count of successful logins in the server.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do if I want to know the exact count of successful
>   logins in the server

Have a look at `last` (below from `man last` my emphasis):

```
NAME
       last, lastb - show a listing of last logged in users

SYNOPSIS
       last [options] [username...] [tty...]
       lastb [options] [username...] [tty...]

DESCRIPTION
       last  searches  back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file desig‐
       nated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged in (and
       out)  since  that  file was created.
```

The `last` command (at least on Debian) shows the lastest logins for the *current month* by default. If you want to catch *all* logins, you could do something like:

```
for log in /var/log/wtmp*; do last -f "$log"; done
```

And then parse the output.